Hyper-V cannot be disabled whatever I do
On Lenovo ThinkPad T14, Ryzen 5 6650U, Windows 11 24H2, I have to use nested hypervisor on VMWare Workstation 17 when using Hyper-V. Because visual performance of VMware is better than Hyper-V.

So I disabled this and related things(including all Hyper-V suboptions, WSL, Windows Virtual Machine Platform, Windows Hypervisor Platform), then reboot. Unfortunately systeminfo gives me Hyper-V detected. I turned it on and off again but same. I recognize that security settings(such DMA Protection, Core Integrity) could take some trouble(Core Integrity is disabled). I know that using command Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All and control panel are equal.
I stopped all Hyper-V services and reboot, however, nothing changes.

I want to say Hyper-V or Windows 11 is weird. Also Virtualbox has this problem(not able to use nested virtual technology), and Nox Player has similar trouble(VT-X not enabled).
should I have extreme choices like touching registry or clean reinstall the OS?
Additional info(Substituted English for non-English);
PS C:\Users\Owner> bcdedit.exe /enum

Windows Booting Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  ko-KR
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {229b8046-8711-11ef-9403-005056c00008}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Booting Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 11
locale                  ko-KR
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {229b8049-8711-11ef-9403-005056c00008}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {229b8046-8711-11ef-9403-005056c00008}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Off


Intel VT-X cannot be enabled on AMD hardware I think you mean AMD-V wasn’t enabled.

I assume you have tried bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off? Anyway post the output of bcdedit /enum by editing your question. Is VBS currently enabled or disabled?

Not sure if or how you would fix the state of failing to remove a feature(is this win server or some win pro?) without saying os is corrupted. Check in your diskpart if disk is "locked" on some level. Also, why HV cant nest? I'm sure i have 2 of them, so hv>vm>vm didnt need more beyond this. (EDIT:ups, forgot this... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/enable-nested-virtualization)

@Danijel - Author indicates they are using Windows 11 24H2, the only consumer edition that has Hyper-V is Windows 11 Professional.

Ouuu,... :$ skipped that as part of PC setup, my bad.
